# Adding Custom Framework in to playground - swift 3.0

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, swift-playground, swift-custom-framework

I am facing issues while importing my custom framework in to the playground. It always says 'No such module'. I have tried adding playground to workspace as well as to the project target but found no luck. In swift files it is working perfectly fine. I have even tried with cocoapods as well(other is manual approach).

I have gone through many post but none of the solution worked for me.
These are some of the links which I referred:

1. http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/#/dev188e45167
2. Issues mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29365604/error-importing-framework-in-playground) post and mine are similar but solution
   didn't worked.

Anyone has any idea about this :/

Comment: Hey @priyanka look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24048331/6536841) and inform if it helps.